# Backup/Restore timeout in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

How to configure backup/restore timeout, if we are restoring from a tape or disk it might stops in the middle.

How to configure a timeout rule for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) syntax,there is no time out option.There is an option called continue after error,which instructs sqlserver  to,not to  cause backup  to fail for torn pages or invalid checksums..